# Adb sleep function working on adb but not in a .sh file

Tags: android, bash, shell, powershell

i am trying to make a simple "tap and wait" script to run on my Android device through adb.

Opening adb on Powershell with the command `./adb shell` works, running `input tap 300 300` works, and running `sleep 1`does sleep for a second.

However, if I run a `test.sh` script with the Powershell command `./adb shell "sh /sdcard/Download/test.sh"` the tapping part still works, but the `sleep` call gives me this instead: `'sdcard/Download/MIOPROGRAMMA.sh[2]: sleep: syntax error: Invalid argument '1` .

Any idea why this happen?

Comment: You should show us some code.. the sleep call might be right in complaining

Answer (score 5):

Just add `;` after the `int`, i.e.:

```
input tap 250 250
sleep 3;
input tap 350 250
sleep 3;
input tap 450 250
sleep 3;
input tap 550 250
sleep 3;
input tap 650 250
sleep 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use powershell's `Start-Sleep` cmdlet ? Have all your logic in the powershell script.

```
$sendTapCmd = "adb shell `"input tap 250 250`" "
$numberOfTaps = 5  

for ($i=0;$i -lt $numberOfTaps;$i++) {
    $output = Invoke-Expression $sendTapCmd
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3
}
```