# adb.exe: unknown command am adb.exe: unknown command sleep error keeps poping up when am trying to run the shell script on my rooted android device

Tags: android, bash, shell, scripting

Hi guys am new to the shell scripting.. please do not mind if acted like a noob.

The following error keeps poping up when am trying to run the shell script on my android device

```
    #!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 100) 
do  
echo "Time: $i"
adb -s $* shell am start com.android.camera/.Camera -W -S
adb -s $* shell sleep 3
adb -s $* shell input tap 540 1994
adb -s $* shell input tap 540 1994
adb -s $* shell input tap 540 1994
count=`adb -s $* shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/ | wc |awk '{print $1}'`
echo Count: $count
if [[ count -gt 500 ]]; then
break
fi
adb -s $* reboot
adb -s $* wait-for-device
adb -s $* shell sleep 40
adb -s $* shell input tap 500 1200
done
```

Result:
adb.exe: unknown command am
adb.exe: unknown command sleep

Comment: Try to add semicolon like in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033807/adb-sleep-function-working-on-adb-but-not-in-a-sh-file/50729474

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596814

Answer (score 2):

you can't run adb commands on your android device. instead the adb binary must installed on host. the script is a linux script and can not run from windows. prepare bootable usb flash drive and run this script from any linux terminal

furthermore some of your commands requires root permissions. therefore `sush` must invited (and permissions granted on superuser app on touchscreen)

```
adb shell su -c "am start com.android.camera/.Camera -W -S"
```

awk is not available on android. to make it more clear that these pipes are actually running on host, quote the android commands (or even better avoid awk at all)

```
count=$(adb shell "ls -1 /sdcard/DCIM/Camera" | wc | awk '{print $1}')
count=$(adb shell "ls -1 /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | wc -l")
```

`am` is actually a shell script pointing to `am.jar` this requires full booted android. if you try to run in recovery mode you should at least run the framework

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads // https://unetbootin.github.io